# Median and percentiles in Kibana geohash grid aggregation

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, aggregation, median, geohashing

I have an index composed by lat,long,country,value that I want to plot both in the region map and the coordinate map.

I want for every bucket (region or grid tile) the median or another percentile, for example 75%, but the only metric aggregation that I can see from Kibana are Average, Count, Sum, Max, ... but not what I'm looking for.

How do you think I can achieve that?

Thanks in advance.